# Apache2 not loading wsgi script

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, pylons, virtualenv, paster

I am setting up CKAN, a pylons application according to these instructions:
http://packages.python.org/ckan/deployment.html

But when I point to the server (no DNS setup yet) using IP or hostname, I only see apache's greeting page, sugesting the ckan app is not being loaded.

here is my mod_wsgi script:

```
import os
instance_dir = '/home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br'
config_file = 'ckan.emap.fgv.br.ini'
pyenv_bin_dir = os.path.join(instance_dir, 'pyenv', 'bin')
activate_this = os.path.join(pyenv_bin_dir, 'activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from paste.deploy import loadapp
config_filepath = os.path.join(instance_dir, config_file)
from paste.script.util.logging_config import fileConfig
fileConfig(config_filepath)
application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
```

here is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName dck093

ServerAlias dck093

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/bin/ckan.emap.fgv.br.py
# pass authorization info on (needed for rest api)
WSGIPassAuthorization On

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ckan.emap.fgv.br.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ckan.emap.fgv.br.custom.log combined
<Directory /home/flavio/var/srvc/ckan.emap.fgv.br/pyenv/bin>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I try to disable the 000-default site (with a2dissite), but that dind't help.After doing this I get an Internal server error page, but no log message. Can anyone point out what am I missing?

Comment: I fixed a conflict that caused paste.deploy to fail importing, and now I am getting log messages (only INFO level ones, no errors) from the ckan app, meaning it is being loaded, but still can't load its page.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using IP to access the server, you should have `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` with the IP you are using or the virtualhost won't load.

Comment: I am using Hostname "http://dck093"

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the debug feature of Pylons does not work with the default multi-process configuration of apache mod_wsgi.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485790/mod-wsgi-pylons-ckan-installation-not-working

for more details.